# element implicitly has an 'any' type error in vue 3 app

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I am trying to use lucidev icons in my component but I am really new in typescript

Here is lucidev: https://github.com/lucide-icons/lucide

```
<template>
  <component :is="icon" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import * as icons from 'lucide-vue-next';
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    size
  },

  computed: {
    icon() {
      return icons[this.name];
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

But I am getting element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type in icons[this.name]

How can I fix this?

icons:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that icons doesn't seem to have a type, which is why it is any. Now you want to use this.name, which is of type string, to access that unknown any type, which TS doesn't like. If you give icons a type, then this should work. For React someone has done it here: https://github.com/lucide-icons/lucide/issues/894#issuecomment-1337582676

Comment: Maybe it is enough to declare an interface like this: 
interface LucideIcons {
    [index: string]: any;
}
and then in computed above the return:
const lucideIcons: LucideIcon = icons;
return lucideIcons[this.name]

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means that the `icons` variable is not the type that you expect it to be.

Often it's because it's an array. In that case, a `string` can't be used to index the type of the array because a `number` is needed to do that. e.g. `icons[2]`.

I would try console logging the icons variable and seeing what comes out, from there you can figure out what you need to use to index it :)

I hope this helps!

Comment: It is an object, I edited my question with the picture

Comment: Hmm... There seems to be a difference between it as an Object and it as a module. Have you tried console logging `icons["Infinity"]`? If that works, then it will be annoyed because it want you to not only have a string, but have one of the very specifically allowed strings.

Comment: Output is like this: ({ size, color, ...props }, { attrs, slots }) => {
  return h(
    "svg",
    {
      ...defaultAttributes,
      width: size || defaultAttributes.width,
      height: size || defaultAttributes.heigh…

Comment: Interesting, then I would try and specify the `name` prop as one of those strings. I'm thinking
```
props: {
    name: {
        required: true,
        validator: (value)=> value in Object.keys(icons)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that works in Vue, but it's worth a shot :)